# Error in .local(drv, ...) : Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.143.13.xxx' (0)

Tags: r, rmysql

I am getting erro in .local(drv,...).
I have no idea how to fix this issue.
Can anyone help me out why showing such a error and how to fix this error?

code:

```
library(RMySQL)

mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='XXXXXXX',                  
password='XXXXXXXX', dbname='XXXXXXXX',
host='##.143.13.XXX', port=XXXX)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [DBI](https://db.rstudio.com/dbi/) and [pool](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pool/versions/0.1.0.9000) packages from R.

```
library(DBI)
library(pool)
pool <- dbPool(drv = RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = "dbName", host = "localhost", username = "root", password = "psw", port = 3306, unix.sock = "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock")
df <- dbGetQuery(pool, "SELECT * FROM tablename;")
```

Provide MySQL socket path of the machine at `unix.sock`(in ubuntu : `mysql_config --socket`)